# How to disable input attribute after 10 clicks?

Tags: javascript, input, disabled-input

I am trying to remove the style or the background of a textbox to reveal the content after 10 clicks. How can I do that on Javascript?

here is my html:

```
<input id="firstN" type="text" style="color:#FF0000; background-color:#FF0000">
```

and here is my JS:

```
 function check() {

    var tries++;

    if (tries == 10){
        document.getElementById('firstN').disabled= true;
    }
}
```

Comment: you're redefining that variable every time the function's executed, so it'll never go past `1`.  definte `tries` OUTSIDE of the function: `var tries = 0;`, then a simple `tries++;` inside the check() function.

Comment: document.getElementById('firstN').disabled= true; doesnt seem to work. When I changed it to alert('blahblah'), it worked. It seems that its able to count the clicks though

Comment: @user1893388 please remember to accept the correct answer for this question :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `tries` is a local variable (local to the `check` function). Every time `check` is called, a new variable named `tries` is created and initialized to 0.

Try this instead:

```
var tries = 0;
function check() {
  tries++;
  if (tries == 10) {
    document.getElementById('firstN').style.background = '#ffffff';
  }
}
```

(I'm assuming that you already have some code to call `check` when the element is clicked. If not, you need to add a [click handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onclick) to your element.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 
I've tried what you suggested and it didnt work.

here is from the html section:
<input id="firstN" type="text" style="color:#FF0000; background-color:#FF0000">

I'm trying to disable the style after 10 clicks

and yes I have the code to call the check()

Comment: document.getElementById('firstN').disabled= true; doesnt seem to work. When I changed it to alert('blahblah'), it worked. It seems that its able to count the clicks though

Comment: You're trying to change the color of the text? Then disabled isn't what you want... try `document.getElementById('firstN').style.color = '#ffffff'` or `document.getElementById('firstN').style.background = '#ffffff'`.

Comment: Yes, definitely. Once I get my 15 reps :)

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating a var "tries" everytime you go into this function.  Move the variable up   a level to where it will increment:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btnclick");
btn.onclick = check;
var tries = 0;
function check() {

    tries++;

    if (tries == 10){
        var ele = document.getElementById("firstN");
        ele.value= "DISABLED";

        ele.disabled = true;
    }
}​
```

EDIT:

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNCodeMonkey/t9M6P/)

Comment: document.getElementById('firstN').disabled= true; doesnt seem to work.
When I changed it to alert('blahblah'), it worked.
It seems that its able to count the clicks though.

Comment: @user1893388 I updated the post with a working fiddle of what you need.  Hope it works for ya!

Answer (score 0):

store it in a cookie:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var clicks = 0;</script>
<input id="firstN" type="text" style="color:#FF0000; background-color:#FF0000" value="Click" onclick="clicks++">

onclick="$.cookie('clicks', $.cookie('clicks') + 1);"
```

Comment: A cookie is really unncessary here imo.

Comment: I guess you're right. This would be better optimized for page to page counting

Comment: Why would this get down voted? I still find this to be a good answer for anyone that needs it based off cookies for obvious reasoning.

Comment: i know, but still, sad face

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Remove the alert lines when you see that it works.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <script>
 function check(){

    var getClicks = parseInt(document.getElementById('firstN').getAttribute('clicks')); //Get Old value

    document.getElementById('firstN').setAttribute("clicks", 1 + getClicks); //Add 1

    if (getClicks === 10){ //Check
        alert('Locked');
        document.getElementById('firstN').disabled= true;
    } else {
        alert(getClicks); //Remove else statement when you see it works.
    }

}

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="#">
    Input Box: <input id="firstN" type="text" style="color:#FF0000; background-color:#FF0000" onclick="check();" clicks="0">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```